# Read contents of a string in an array in PHP

Tags: php

How can I separate age from name of a person in the following string in PHP ?

```
ASHLEY TURNER               4 y, 0 m
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Advice: look at PHP's [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). Also look at [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Write some code. Come back and edit your question with your code and a more specific question regarding that code.

Comment: Why is it in that format to begin with? Where is the original data coming from? A database?

Answer (score -1):

Is it always in the same format? So number + y?
To only get the age, you can use the following:

```
preg_match('/(\d+) y/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

To get both name and age, use this:

```
preg_match('/([aA-zZ ]+)(\d+) y/', $string, $match);
$name = trim($match[1]);
$age = $match[2];
```